# JQuery UI Slider doesn't work with "value: x", only with "values: [x]"

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

Here's the JSFiddle Link: (http://jsfiddle.net/jforman07/qaU7K/222/).

**Problem:** The slider bar doesn't move

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 50,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,

    slide: function (event, ui) {

         $("input.sliderValue[data-index=0]").val("$" + ui.values[0] + "k");

        var delay = function () {
            var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).data('index.uiSliderHandle');

            $("#slideText").html(ui.value).position({
                my: 'center top',
                at: 'center bottom',
                of: ui.handle,
                offset: "0, -74"
            });
        };
        setTimeout(delay, 0);
     }
 });


});
```

If I change

```
value: 50,
```

to

```
values: [50],
```

then the slider bar works, but then the green shading on the slider bar disappears - as seen in this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jforman07/qaU7K/223/

Comment: Thanks!  just edited original question to include the javascript code

Comment: It's best to use the debugging tools you have available to you to figure out problems. In this case, if you'd looked in the JavaScript console of your browser, you'd have seen `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` on the line [@hearaman points out in his/her answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17500833/157247). Using the debugger built into your browser to stop on that line would let you inspect the `ui` object, at which point you presumably would see that it had no `values` property but did have a `value` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#slider").slider(options = {
    range: "min",
    value: 50,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,

    slide: function (event, ui) {


        var delay = function () {
            var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).data('index.uiSliderHandle');

            $("#slideText").html(ui.value).position({
                my: 'center top',
                at: 'center bottom',
                of: ui.handle,
                offset: "0, -74"
            });
             $(".sliderValue").val("$" + ui.value + "k");
        };

        setTimeout(delay, 0);


    },
    create : function (event, ui){
     $(".sliderValue").val("$" + options.value+ "k");

    }
});


});
```

A: use the create  option as a callback function when the slider is done. the UI is empty, so we have to name our options, as you can see in params it's `(options = {...})` this will allow us to fetch the preset value by calling `options.value` 
B: you should make the slider label update while in the delay function.

Answer (score 2):

Just, change a line in your code as bellow

From

```
       $("input.sliderValue[data-index=0]").val("$" + ui.values[0] + "k");
```

To

```
       $("input.sliderValue[data-index=0]").val("$" + ui.value + "k");
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaU7K/226/)